# Search multiple items returning error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel formula that I want to return the rightmost data after finding one of three things. However if the first search term is not found it returns an error:

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-SEARCH({")",">","#"},A1)),"")
```

How can I make this work for all three search terms?

Currently the other search terms evaluate to #VALUE! which, if the first term is not found, is causing the formula to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modified version, entered as an Array formula (Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter rather than just Enter)

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH({")",">","#"},A1),0)))
```

The `Max` get the largest result from `Search`.

If none of the characters appear in the string, it returns the whole string

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that still doesn't work. When the search returns an error the IFERROR nulls it which makes MAX look for zero. I can correct this to: =RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(")",A1),0),IFERROR(SEARCH(">",A1),0),IFERROR(SEARCH("#",A1),0))) but is there any way to make this more elegant?

Comment: Did you enter as an _Array Formula_ ?  See image

Comment: I've just realised you said CSE... and it works! Unfortunately I'm generating the formula from a vbscript... I guess it's time to learn how to enter a CSE formula from vbscript, then!

Comment: @fileinster `YourRange.FormulaArray  = ...`